# SQL: Subtract one query from another

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have two tables called tbl1 & tbl2 (different number of columns and IDs), and I get the monthly total of each table using the following queries:

query1:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(tbl1_date), SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4) 
FROM myTbl1 
GROUP BY YEAR(tbl1_date), MONTH(tbl1_date);
```

query2:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(tbl2_date), SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4+col5+col6) 
FROM myTbl2 
GROUP BY YEAR(tbl2_date), MONTH(tbl2_date);
```

How can I subtract query2 from query1 and get the difference of SUMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the two queries and then subtract.

```
SELECT t1.month, t1.year, t1.total - t2.total AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT MONTHNAME(tbl1_date) AS month, YEAR(tbl1_date) AS year, SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4) AS total
    FROM myTbl1 
    GROUP BY YEAR(tbl1_date), MONTH(tbl1_date)
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MONTHNAME(tbl2_date) AS month, YEAR(tb2_date) AS year, SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4+col5+col6) AS total
    FROM myTbl2 
    GROUP BY YEAR(tbl2_date), MONTH(tbl2_date)
) AS t2 ON t1.month = t2.month AND t1.year = t2.year
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables could have different months *and* you want all rows, then you really want a `full join`.  MySQL does not support that, but you can use `union all` and `group by` in this case:

```
SELECT yyyy, mon, SUM(s) - SUM(s2) as diff
FROM ((SELECT YEAR(tbl1_date) as yyyy,
              MONTHNAME(tbl1_date) as mon, 
              SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4) as s1, 0 as s2
       FROM myTbl1 
       GROUP BY YEAR(tbl1_date), MONTH(tbl1_date)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT YEAR(tbl2_date) as yyyy,
              MONTHNAME(tbl2_date) as mon, 
              0, SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4) as s2
       FROM myTbl12
       GROUP BY YEAR(tbl2_date), MONTH(tbl2_date)
      )
     ) ym
GROUP BY yyyy, mon;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. In this case, tables have the same months and I need months in order. Thanks again!